# TypeError: login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have written a login view using build-in auth ,django `auth.login()` gives above error my code with error code o 500

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,logout,login


@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
    user=User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'],email=request.POST['email'],password=request.POST['password'])
    return Response({'ok':'True'},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    user=authenticate(
        username=request.POST['username'],
        password=request.POST['password']
    )
    if user is not None:
        login(request,user)
        return Response({'ok':'True'},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({'ok':'False'},status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Your view has the same name as the auth login function, so it is hiding it. Change the view name, or import the function under a different name eg `from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login`.

Answer (score 8):

You have a function `def login` and a library import with the same name.

What you need is to change one of them.

Example :

```
- def user_login  // import login as Login_process
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not use same name for your `def` whom you imported.
so change your `def name` from `def login` to another one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your def name using another name because name of your your module and function