# login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given using django

Tags: python, django

I dont know why i receiving this error **login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**, ive just follow this tutorial that after sign-up it will login automatic https://www.csestack.org/django-sign-up-registration-form/

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("test")
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            user.contact_number = form.cleaned_data.get('contact_number')
            user.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.save()
            insert = Customer(
                user=user,
                first_name=user.first_name,
                last_name=user.last_name,
                contact_number=user.contact_number,
                email=user.email
            )
            insert.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            users = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, users)
            return redirect('Homepage')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'mysite/login.html', {'form': form})
```

> this is the traceback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\clair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\clair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\clair\OneDrive\Desktop\Thesis\mysite\myapp\views.py", line
> 36, in login
> login(request, users)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /login/ Exception Value: login() takes 1
> positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316948/typeerror-login-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 3):

Your view function is called `login()` – rename it to e.g. `login_view` so it does not shadow the Django `login()` function you've imported and are trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your function with the same name of the imported function (i.e., `login`), you override it.  So, you can't use it try to add `_view` for any function view to not face this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

A short bit of detail for you to understand what's happening here.

When you've imported Django's `login` method, then you went ahead and defined your own method also called `login`, that's what caused the issue here because of the function (*your defined login method*) is calling itself rather than Django's `login` method.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login  # Importing django's login method

# This is your defined method which takes one argument
def login(request):
     ...

     # Because having the same name as the Django method imported, it's calling itself instead.
     # Therefore you're getting an error here since it's calling itself and you're passing two arguments.
     login(request, users)

     ...
```

Therefore, as mentioned by the others, just rename your defined `login` method to allow the program to call the Django `login` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the view name, or import the function under a different name eg

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
```