# Django Authenticate function always returns nine even after making required changes in the settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

I am trying to create a login system with Django python. Though the Authenticate function always returns none even after making certain changes in the settings.py as suggested in other StackOverflow answers. I have tried running this code in debug mode in visual studio code and found out the problem lies in the authenticate function only as it's always none and the code hence is never able to log in any user.

Here is my code:

1. views.py(login function)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Home_Page.html')


def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if User.objects.filter(username=request.POST.get('username').upper()).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'The username already exists')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=request.POST.get('email').lower()).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'The Email already exists')

            else:

                user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST.get('username').upper(), email=request.POST.get('email').lower(), password=request.POST.get(
                    'password'), first_name=request.POST.get('firstname'), last_name=request.POST.get('lastname'))

                user.save()

                return redirect('home')

        return render(request, 'Signup_Page.html')
    else:
        return redirect('/dashboard')


def login(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get(
                'username'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/dashboard')
            else:

                return render(request, 'Login_Page.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'Login_Page.html')
    else:
        return redirect('/dashboard')


def logout(request):
    if not request.user.is_anonymous:
        logout(request)

        return HttpResponse("Home Page")
    return redirect('/')
```

2. Login_Page.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(54, 182, 107), rgb(53, 29, 190))
    }
    
    .text-center {
      text-align: center !important;
    }
    
    .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .btn-block {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .btn-group-lg>.btn,
    .btn-lg {
      padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      line-height: 1.5;
      border-radius: 0.3rem;
    }
    
    .btn-primary {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #007bff;
      border-color: #007bff;
    }
    
    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1.5;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    [type=reset],
    [type=submit],
    button,
    html [type=button] {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
    }
    
    button,
    select {
      text-transform: none;
    }
    
    button,
    input {
      overflow: visible;
    }
    
    button,
    input,
    optgroup,
    select,
    textarea {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-size: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
    }
    
    button {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    
    *,
     ::after,
     ::before {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .form-signin {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d7da;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 330px;
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #34B8B0;
      border-radius: 40px
    }
    
    .form-signin .checkbox {
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .form-signin .form-control {
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: auto;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .form-signin .form-control:focus {
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .form-signin input[type="text"] {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    }
    
    .form-signin input[type="password"] {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    
    .btn-primary {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #007bff;
      border-color: #007bff;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="text-center">
  {% for msg in messages %}
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    {{msg}}

  </div>

  {% endfor %}

  <form class="form-signin" method='POST' action='/login'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-10 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <input type="text" name='username' id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="password" name='password' id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <br>
    <a style="margin-right: 50%;
                      margin-bottom: 50%;" name='signup' id='signup' href='/forgotpassword'>Forgot password</a>
    <br>
    <button style="margin-top: 4%;
                           margin-bottom: 4%;" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
            Sign in
        </button>
    <br>
    <a class='text' name='signup' id='signup' href='/signup'>Create an account</a>
  </form>



</body>

</html>
```

3. Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for DjangoJeeWebsite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-pvq6esb&x2f$%smc$$4m2@%ovybo7sb-qxfz1^q_-j=d%da-_&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Index',
    'Dashboard',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoJeeWebsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoJeeWebsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

Comment: When creating the user you convert the username to uppercase, do you need to do that or do you need to convert to uppercase in the login view?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington Oh my god that was the problem I was soo confused with all the mess I made in the views file that I had forgotten the change I made in username. Thank You for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Iain Shelvington, the issue starts from where a user is being created with the `username` set to `uppercase` -> `username=request.POST.get('username').upper()`.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST.get('username').upper(), email=request.POST.get('email').lower(), password=request.POST.get('password'), first_name=request.POST.get('firstname'), last_name=request.POST.get('lastname'))
```

Then the way you're passing the `username` to the `authenticate()` is without the `upper()`.

```
user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
```

So you could remove the `upper()` from the username when creating a user, or add the `upper()` to the username in the `authenticate()`.

On a side note though, I see where you have two methods called `login()`. The Django `login()` and a defined method `login()`. This might cause a bit of an issue for you as well. I'd suggest that you rename your defined `login()` to something like: `login_view()` so it doesn't shadow the Django `login()`. For example:

```
# your defined method here; rename to login_view:
def login_view(request):
     ...
     # so it won't shadow the login method from Django
     login(request, users)
     ...
```

Else you'll get an error like:

> Exception Type: TypeError at /login/ Exception Value: login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

You could take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72669342/15978450) to get a better understanding if needs be.